# Problema de codificación en cadenas de texto usando SerenityBDD

Tags: java, selenium, test, cucumber, serenity-bdd

Tengo un inconveniente a la hora de extraer el texto de una tabla de elementos dado que el texto resultante viene con un problema de codificación en cuanto a las tildes generando problemas a la hora de hacer aserciones.

Aquí una imagen de como me muestra la lista **[Las palabras señaladas en rojo son con las que tengo problemas]**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi configuración de ambiente es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí la lista que estoy extrayendo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código que utilizo para extraer dicha lista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí la imagen de la configuración en serenity.properties que tengo en SerenityBDD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí las librerías que utilizo:

```
/**
 * Apply plugins to the build
 **/
plugins{
    id "java"
    id "eclipse"
    id "idea"
    id "net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin" version "4.0.27"
}

group "co.ael"
version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

/**
 * Define the locations where dependencies can be found
 **/
repositories { mavenCentral() }

/**
 *  This section sets the current version supported by Java
 * */
java {
    sourceCompatibility = 16
    targetCompatibility = 16
}

/**
 *  This section establishes the versions of the libraries to be used
 **/
ext {
    serenity_version = "4.0.15"
    junit_platform_launcher_version =" 1.10.0"
    cucumber_junit_platform_engine_version = "7.14.0"
    junit_platform_suite_version = "1.10.0"
    junit_jupiter_engine_version = "5.9.3"
    junit_vintage_engine_version = "5.9.3"
    logback_classic_version = "1.2.10"
    assertj_core_version = "3.23.1"
    slf4j_version = "2.0.5"
}

/**
 *  Section where the different libraries are defined
 **/
dependencies {
    implementation(
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:${serenity_version}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenity_version}",
            "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:${cucumber_junit_platform_engine_version}",
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4j_version}",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logback_classic_version}",
            "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertj_core_version}"
    )
    testImplementation(
            "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:${junit_platform_suite_version}",
            "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junit_jupiter_engine_version}",
            "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junit_vintage_engine_version}",
            "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:${junit_platform_launcher_version}"
    )
}

/**
 * In this section the test parameters and the test engine are configured.
 * */
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "cucumber.filter.tags", System.getProperty("cucumber.filter.tags")
    systemProperties(System.properties)
    testLogging { showStandardStreams = true }
}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
test.finalizedBy(aggregate)
```